# How to check the output only contains a specific string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I use following shell script

```
if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ] && [ -z $(ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}') ]
then
    echo $line
    echo $line >> hostlist_available
fi
```

I would like to do following:

**Under the condition that `[ $RESULT -eq 0 ]` holds, 
either `[ -z $(ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}') ]` or `$(ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}') only contains string "zwang10"` holds, we still continue the loop.**

The command `$(ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}') ]` will output like following cases:

Only one of my name

```
zwang10
```

Several my names

```
zwang10
zwang10
```

Some others name

```
jack
jack
ben
```

Other names and mine

```
jack
zwang10
zwang10
```

How can test whether the output only contains my name `zwang10`?

**Revised**
I tried to addd condition in the if

```
  if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ] && [ [-z $(ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}')] || [[ $(ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}') == 'zwang10' ]]]
    then
        echo $line
        echo $line >> hostlist_available
fi
```

But it says `syntax error in conditional expression`

Comment: `[[ $(ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}') == 'zwang10' ]]`

Comment: @anubhava. Thank you. But I have trouble to add the above sentence to the if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
if [[ $RESULT -eq 0 ]]; then
   output=$(ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}')

   if [[ -z $output || $output == 'zwang10' ]]; then
      echo $line
      echo $line >> hostlist_available
   fi
fi
```

Comment: Actually, only when `[[ $RESULT -eq 0 ]]`, then I can have `ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}'`, how can I do it? Otherwise, `ssh` fails. `$RESULTS` is a result of whether `ssh` succeeds or not.

Comment: When the output contains multiple same names `zwang10` as in case 2, your code does not `echo $line`. But I want it to `echo $line`